# How to provide intellisense with the datacontext type in a resharper plugin?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resharper, resharper-sdk

When writing a wpf prism app, I use the `ViewModelLocator` to automatically create the datacontext when needed. While this works great, there's no intellisense help unless I add a designtime datacontext (`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MyViewModel}"`), but that somewhat defeats the purpose of automatically discovering and connecting the viewmodel.

I image something like this: a resharper plugin that looks for `ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"` in the xaml, fetches the class name, derives the viewmodel type and then tells intellisense to use this type as datacontext.

*Question: is it possible for a resharper plugin to tell intellisense what is the type of the datacontext without the designtime datacontext?*

*Ancillary question: can you give a complete resharper sdk beginner a hint on how to accomplish this?*

Comment: Are you using MVVMLight?

Comment: Here's an upvote. I had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that part of ReSharper is not extensible - it will only work with data set in the file. There is an issue suggesting extending by use of annotations, which is a nice idea - you can vote on it, add details and track: [RSRP-385725](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-385725)