# xaml viewmodel declaration in prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am using PRISM with xamarin forms, and I like to declare my viewmodels in the XAML,

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProyect.ViewModels"
```

……

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:RegistroPageViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

so I can have XAML intellicense, in this sample my RegistroPageViewModel constructor have one parameter beacause it need for the base class but I don't know how to pass it within the xaml

```
public class RegistroPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RegistroPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService):base(navigationService)
    {
        registro = new RegistroInfo();
        Title = "Perfil de usuario";
    }
```

My specific question is: How can I still using XAML viemodels's declaration if the viewmodel have a parameter ? how can I pass a parameter in the XAML declaration?

thnaks in advance

Comment: You might want to upvote here and the linked resharper issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941300/how-to-provide-intellisense-with-the-datacontext-type-in-a-resharper-plugin

Answer (score 0):

For XAML to know about ViewModel, enable [XamlC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc) and [Compiled Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings). Documentation provides how to enable and use them properly.

XamlC checks for general compile time errors like property names and open-closing matching tags etc...

Compiled Bindings checks for existence of any property that is bound

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view model locator (`ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"`) to have the view model created for you with all dependencies automatically injected.

Setting the view model as design data context (`d:DataContext={d:DesignInstance local:RegistroPageViewModel}`) should give you intellisense.